# How can I avoid my Express API being blocked by corporate firewalls

Tags: mysql, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, firewall

I have a production built React App being served from S3, via CloudFront, with DNS being done on Route 53 - and the homepage is rendered well from within my corporate firewall.

My issue is that it is unable to fetch data from the Express API (which connects to a MySQL DB) to populate the drop downs.

The express API is hosted on an AWS server on LightSail, (it’s glorified EC2, as it is accessed through http via IP:port), but is also accessed via Route 53 which points to S3, and eventually to the IP port combo.

I know that my corporate network also blocks :80, but I haven’t lost hope in somehow getting it to be accessible because the App is able to be served from S3 with no issues, so perhaps there is a workaround here.

It works perfectly from outside my corporate firewall, but I want/need it to be reachable from other companies, and I fear the IP is the turnoff for the firewalls here. Does anyone have any ideas how to make the API more corporate friendly, or a different way to architect the API so that this data can be retrieved in much the same way that the main code can be retrieved from S3 currently?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: This part is a bit confusing *but is also accessed via Route 53 which points to S3, and eventually to the IP port combo.*. Also you say *It works perfectly from outside my corporate firewall*, but you want it *reachable from other companies*. Wouldn't other companies reach it without any issues if it work well from outside your corporate firewall?

Comment: Hi - what I mean by that is that the express API is accessible on <iP>:<port>. I’ve got S3 wrapping it to remove the need to reference the port, and then Route 53 gives it a friendly domain. Ultimately though, the request resolves to an IP:port combo so it gets blocked by the corporate firewall. I would like to avoid this as I would imagine other corporate firewalls blocking random IP:port combos also (mine isn’t the most stringent in general). If I could reference it in a different way, for example, by using the API gateway, or by adding SSL to the API call then perhaps this might help...

Comment: This was solved by setting the port to be :80 and then routing to the IP address only. I set to SSL after just to be sure anyway!

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Can you tell me your solution in more detail? Like what application/command/method you use to do so? I'm looking forward to seeing your troubleshooting guideline.

Comment: First get the app working on 80 or 443 depending on whether you're using http or https, i.e. httpsServer.listen(443....  This will mean it will direct automatically when the http or https request is sent to the server IP. That's all you need to make it work, but you can also choose to setup a record in AWS Route 53 to direct from domain to server IP and make it nicer for the user.